# I cannot find the form.shown event handler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I have added reference to System.Windows.Forms. But I cannot find Form.Shown event handler in the properties-eventhandler window.
Please help me.

Is there any alternative for the same?

Answer (score 3):

When you are using WPF, you can not use WinForms. Those are not the same. You must use the Events from the Window class in WPF.

I assume you use WPF since the WPF tag is there.

For a WPF window I would use one of the following events:

- [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated.aspx) Occurs when a window becomes the foreground window.
- [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) Occurs when this element gets logical focus.
- [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.
- [StateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.statechanged.aspx) Check if WindowState == WindowState.Normal

Answer (score 1):

The WPF equivalent handlers you are possibly looking for are Loaded() and/or Activated(). You might also look at SizeChanged()